# Haskell to Clojure

Tags: haskell, clojure

I am going over this haskell lecture on [count down game](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Graham-Hutton-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-11-of-13/), i don't know any haskell but i am intrested in the problem, i am trying to port his code to clojure.

this is the part i got stuck must be something i don't get in haskell,

```
split                :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
split []              = [([],[])]
split (x:xs)          = ([],x:xs) : [(x:ls,rs) | (ls,rs)  [([a],[a])]
nesplit               = filter ne . split

ne                   :: ([a],[b]) -> Bool
ne (xs,ys)            = not (null xs || null ys)

exprs                :: [Int] -> [Expr]
exprs []              = []
exprs [n]             = [Val n]
exprs ns              = [e | (ls,rs)
```

I have my own split given 1 2 3 4 it spits out,

```
(((1) (2 3 4)) ((1 2) (3 4)) ((1 2 3) (4)))
```

```
(defn split [v]
  (if (= (count v) 1)
    (list (first v))
    (map #(list (take % v) (drop % v)) (range 1 (count v)))))

(defn exprs [v]
  (if (= (count v) 1) 
    v
    (map #(concat (exprs (first %)) (exprs (second %))) v)))

(exprs (split [1 2 3 4]))
```

that gives me,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer
```

Can anyone tell me what am i missing from the haskell code?

His full code listing is available [here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/countdown.hs).

Comment: Is the last line of your Haskell code missing a closing square bracket?

Comment: I had a look at the same problem here, though more brute force like than Graham Hutton's elegant solution.  See http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2009/02/countdown.html

Comment: thanks alot jeff, i was trying the brute force method anyways.

Answer (score 4):

This is closely following the Haskell implementation as far as my limited Haskell fu allows me to do....

```
(defn split
  [s]
  (map #(split-at % s) (range 1 (count s))))

(defn ne
  [s]
  (every? (complement empty?) s))

(defn nesplit
  [s]
  (filter ne (split s)))

(declare combine)

(defn exprs
  [s]
  (when-let [s (seq s)]
    (if (next s)
      (for [[ls rs] (nesplit s)
            l       (exprs ls)
            r       (exprs rs)
            e       (combine l r)]
        e)
      s)))
```

Haven't tested it though.

As for your error message: I think the problem is, that you don't call `split` recursively in `exprs`. Then you get `1`  were a sequence is expected...

Random other note: `count` is linear in time for sequences. Since we just need to know, whether we have more than one element, we can check the value of `(next s)` against `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

the exception results from exprs being called recursively and eventually being invoked with a list of integers.  your code only handles a list of lists or a list of length one.

```
(exprs '(2 3 4))
```

leads to the else branch of the if statement which expands out to:

```
(map #(concat (exprs (first %)) (exprs (second %))) '(2 3 4))))
```

which comes out to:

```
(concat (exprs (first 2)) (exprs (second 2))) 
(concat (exprs (first 3)) (exprs (second 3))) 
(concat (exprs (first 4)) (exprs (second 4)))
```

and (first 2) throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer
```